# Login y register en Android con FOSUserBundle y OAuth2

Tags: android, symfony2

¡Buenas! Estoy haciendo una aplicación en `Android`. Ya tengo mi `REST Api` creada en `Symfony2` y ahora quiero hacer un `register` y `login` en `Android` utilizando `FOSUserBundle` y `OAuth2`. Pero no entiendo cómo hacerlo correctamente. ¿Me echaríais una mano? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Podrias dejar el codigo de lo que haz intentado hacer y los errores que esto te causa, la idea es solucionar errores y no entregarte un codigo sin que entiendas que estas haciendo

Comment: Buenas! El problema es que soy nuevo en este tema y no sabría realmente por donde empezar, sé hacer peticiones Volley y demás pero no sé ni entiendo muy bien esos bundles ni como hacer la peticion para que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Igual te sirve este enlace:

https://gist.github.com/tjamps/11d617a4b318d65ca583

Y tienes este otro Bundle:

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: Si, habia visto ya eso y en principio tengo todo preparado, pero a la hora de hacer el login en android y el registro, no sé cómo implementar los request y demás, los datos que le tengo que pasar, etc.. Estoy un poco liado